# How to get the byte[] used to construct a String?

Tags: java, string, character-encoding, arrays

I have some binary data that is being encoded as a UTF-8 string. How can I get the original data back from the string? The binary data is in no particular character encoding, so I'm not sure what conversion will give me what I want. Consider the following minimal example:

```
byte[] input = { -84 };
String s = new String(input, Charset.forName("UTF8"));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s.getBytes())); // prints [63] 
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s.getBytes("UTF8"))); // prints [-17, -65, -67]
```

And I'm looking for a method that gives me back `[-84]`.

Comment: What does the byte value `-84` decode to in UTF8?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your question. If I print `s` I get `?`. If I evaluate `Character.getNumericValue(s.charAt(0))` I get `-1`.

Comment: How do you decode the value -84 with UTF-8? UTF-8 is a well-defined character encoding. What does the value -84 transform to?

Comment: I would assume it's not possible.

Comment: `-84` is `AC`, which I don't see on the UTF-8 character table.

Comment: `String(byte[] bytes, Charset charset)` has led you astray. [This method always replaces malformed-input and unmappable-character sequences with this charset's default replacement string. **The CharsetDecoder class should be used when more control over the decoding process is required.**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String-byte:A-java.nio.charset.Charset-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, you can't. Not all byte sequences are valid UTF-8. Therefore data might be corrupted in the (error-tolerant) `byte[]->char[]->byte[]` process.

You could use [`ISO_8859_1`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets.html#ISO_8859_1) encoding though, it is a one-to-one mapping for `byte<->char`

This is not an uncommon problem. Many aged protocols, like HTTP, were started with `ISO_8859_1` chars in mind, or, C's `char` type. A newer version of spec would say it's based on "octets", aka "bytes". If your API uses string to represent them, `ISO_8859_1` is often the better choice.

Answer (score 2):

The byte `-84` (`0xAC`) on its own is not a valid UTF-8 byte sequence. (UTF-8 uses the bytes outside the 0 to 127 range only in multibyte character sequences, for encoding exotic characters.) Therefore the UTF-8 decoder replaces the input byte with the character [U+FFFD](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0fffd/index.htm), the Unicode "replacement character". (This may display as a plain question mark in your console.) There is no way to recover the original byte array from that string, since other invalid byte sequences would also decode to the replacement character.

You could do the following:

- Interpret the binary data as a character encoding that has a 1-to-1 mapping between bytes and characters. ISO-8859-1 is the most convenient choice for that since it is one of the six basic encodings guaranteed to be available on any Java implementation, and has a predefined [`StandardCharsets`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets.html#ISO_8859_1) constant. Any old DOS codepage (e.g., [`Charset.forName("CP437")`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437)) will also work if present.

or

- Roll your own `byte[]` to `char[]` conversion. The exact mapping is arbitrary and can be anything you like, so long as it is lossless. Potentially you could halve the size of each string in memory by packing two bytes in each Java `char`, since that type is 16 bits wide, but it is probably not worth the fuss.

or

- [Encode the binary data as text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-to-text_encoding), such as by [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64). Such encoding on its own will make the data longer, but could make it shorter if the string gets additional encoding anyway.

  For example, if you are trying to pass binary data as a parameter [in a URL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_encoding), it makes sense to Base64-encode it. Take a byte array of length 256 containing 1 of each possible byte value (which will serve as a model for any uniformly random, compressed, or encrypted data). If encoded in Base64 with padding stripped and using the modified URL-safe Base64 alphabet, it will take 342 characters, but will not grow any longer or change at all when URL-encoded and passed as a URL query parameter. Whereas, the same byte array being "decoded" as if it were an ISO-8859-1 string would take only 256 characters, but grow to an obese 634 characters the moment it gets put it in a URL, since URL encoding is optimized for plain text, not binary data.

or

- Avoid passing binary data as strings in the first place. Use byte arrays directly if at all possible. If your purpose is to get string features such as immutability and `indexOf` searches on byte data, it would be nicer to make a wrapper class for the arrays instead.

Comment: @AndyShulman No. `-84` and `-19` in binary are `10101100` and `11101101`. Compare those to the description of UTF-8 byte sequences [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description). You see bytes matching `10xxxxxx` are only valid as second and subsequent bytes of multibyte sequences, and bytes matching `1110xxxx` are only valid if they have exactly two `10xxxxxx` bytes after them. So that data is still invalid UTF-8, and hence why those two bytes ends up as a pair of `63`s (which are question mark characters).